# Why do I get a thread context switch every time I synchronize with a mutex?

Tags: multithreading, mutex, thread-synchronization, context-switch

I have multiple threads updating a single array in tight loops. (10 threads on a dual-core processor @ roughly 100000 updates per second). Each time the array is updated under the protection of a mutex (WaitForSingleObject / ReleaseMutex). I have noticed that no thread ever does two consecutive updates to the array which means there must be some sort of yield relating to the synchronization. This means there are about 100000 context switches happening every second which seems sub-optimal. Why does this happen ?

Comment: what is the priority of each thread?

Comment: All threads are identical priority

Comment: how are you calling `WaitForSingleObject` exactly? Specially, what time-out are you giving to it? If you are using INFINITE, I guess this will be the expected behavior

Comment: I am using infinite but I would expect each thread to use up its timeslice (many consecutive updates before context switch)

Comment: Maybe this is because of the multi processor. When the first thread (running on the first processor) release the mutex, the second thread (on the second processor) got it, then when the first thread try to get the mutex, it can not. When the mutex is finally released by the second thread, it is taken by the third thread (on the first processor).

Comment: You might be onto something there. So just to clarify, you are saying that this is happening because there are 2 physical processor and there will always be a thread waiting to grab the mutex as soon as it is released ? So if there was only 1 core then each thread would run for a full timeslice and do many consecutive updates ?

Comment: Yeah, that must be it. Stick your last comment in an answer and I'll give you a tick :)

Comment: I did not try it but I am almost sure that is the problem. Do you have access to a single processor machine?

Comment: When 10 threads try to acquire a mutex then 9 are going to lose.  Single array + tight loop + many threads is a poor combination, you can't get concurrency when your code won't allow it.  Google "amdahl's law".

Comment: @Hans Passant : I'm getting LOTS of concurrency !

Comment: @Kevin MOLCARD - sorry, I've changed my mind, I don't think it is multiple physical processors at work :(

Comment: @FunkyOordvork: no problem, at least now you will keep it in mind :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that there is an order of all waiting threads.

Each thread blocked in a WaitForSingleObject goes into a queue and is then suspended by the scheduler so that it does not eat up execution time anymore. When the mutex is freed, one of the waiting threads is resumed by the scheduler. It is unspecified what the exact order is in which threads are wakened from the queue, but in many cases it will be a simple first-in, first-out.

What happens now is that if the same thread releases the mutex and then does another WaitForSingleObject on the same mutex, he is going to be re-inserted into the queue and it is quite unlikely that he will be inserted at the front of the queue if there are already other threads waiting. This makes sense, as allowing him to skip to the front of the queue could lead to other threads starving. So the scheduler will probably just suspend him and wake the the thread that is at the front of the queue instead.

Comment: Are you saying that the scheduler runs every time a call to ReleaseMutex is made ?

Comment: Not necessarily. But your thread will have to wait for the scheduler whenever he calls a `WaitForSingleObject` and there are already other threads waiting for the same mutex.

Comment: But it will only have to wait for the scheduler if the mutex is taken by another thread ?

Comment: That depends on the implementation. The syscall triggered by `WaitForSingleObject` would be allowed to return early in this case, but that is just an optimization. However, if he did return early if there are threads waiting that would cause unfair scheduling. The first case is a matter of efficiency, the latter is one of correctness.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because of the multi processor.

When the first thread (running on the first processor) release the mutex, the second thread (on the second processor) got it, then when the first thread try to get the mutex, it can not. When the mutex is finally released by the second thread, it is taken by the third thread (on the first processor).

Comment: A waiting thread should not get scheduled _at all_ on modern operating systems. The scheduler knows that the thread cannot continue as long as the mutex is locked, so he won't assign any timeslice to it. Try it yourself: Spinning on a this_thread::yield() in C++ will always waste a full CPU core, while calling lock() on a mutex or wait() on a condition_variable will not.

Comment: @ComicSansMS: I have read your answer and that's what I expected but was not sure. All the `WaitForSingleObject` are in a queue so a thread will be after all the other thread after he calls `ReleaseMutex`. That's also why I asked @FunkyOordvork if he has access to single core machine.

Comment: @ComicSansMS you are right, a waiting thread is not running, so the scheduler must be running every time there is a release, which does seem sub-optimal, but that might just be down to my lack of knowledge !

Comment: It would indeed be interesting to check whether the behavior is the same when using only one core. A few calls to [`SetThreadAffinityMask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should do the trick.

Comment: @FunkyOordvork An operating systems engineer might argue that your use of mutexes is sub-optimal instead ;)  Why release the mutex in the first place if you have to re-lock it right away? You can probably get around the whole issue by restructuring your code in a way that this situation no longer occurs.

Comment: @ComicSansMS I think a lot of threads do exactly that when operating on shared data. If I lock and release outside my loop instead of inside then the other threads don't get a look in and I have become the scheduler

Comment: @ComicSansMS Using SetThreadAffinityMask doesn't change the behaviour